# How can i use code in a variable in python?

Tags: python

I tried with `exec()` but it doesn't work for what i'm trying to do:

```
math = "1 + 1"
a = exec(math)
print(a)
```

when "a" is printed i get

```
None
```

how can i do something like this?

Comment: You can try `eval()` but it will only be executed once. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `exec()` doesn't return the value.  You would have to include the assignment in the exec expression: `exec("a = 1 + 1")`.  However, this is almost certainly a terrible idea, and there must be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: i need to take a math operation as input to use it for some stuff. I thoght this was the fastest way to do this but as i see it's very unsafe.

Comment: You’re probably better off using something like sympy.

Answer (score 2):

```py
exec("a = 1 + 1")
print(a)
```

```py
2
```

```py
b = eval("1 + 1")
print(b)
```

```py
2
```

You're getting `None` because `exec` always returns `None`, instead it execute the expression. What you might want is `eval`, it returns whatever is evaluated inside.

Notice that both of them are quite dangerous as malicious programs can easily assess your data by input.

[Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)